# how to get width of a div in css :100%-1px

Tags: html, width

Is there any way to calculate width in CSS? I want to make a  with the width 1px less than the 100% width. 
Is there any property like `width:100%-1px;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript snippet:

```
elem = document.getElementById('div');
pElem = elem.parentNode;
pPadding = pElem.style.padding || pElem.style.paddingLeft + pElem.style.paddingRight || 0;
pBorder = pElem.style.borderWidth || pElem.style.borderLeftWidth + pElem.style.borderRightWidth || 0;    
elem.style.width = ( pElem.offsetWidth - pPadding - pBorder - 4 ) + "px";
```

**Edit:** It's important to note that in this script, 3 = 0, 4 = 1, 5 = 2, 6 = 3, ect... so 3 is like the starting number.

Comment: There seems to be something off as it makes the div wider than the original 100%. Even when specifying `elem.style.width = ( pElem.offsetWidth - pPadding - pBorder - 0 ) + "px";` with a `0` it also makes the div wider as the original 100%. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8QDm/ The inner div is 100% but after running the script with `0` or even the original `1` it is wider than 100%. Would that have something to do with the borders or maybe even the browser? I only tested it in latest Chrome.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I'm running Chrome to... and you're right... it's important to note that in this script, 3 = 0, 4 = 1, 5 = 2, 6 = 3, ect... so 3 is like the starting number. Don't really know why that's happening... :}